# ApplicationExitInfo REASON_SIGNALED meaning in Android

Tags: android, performance

In my application, one of the reason for application Exit is 2 which refers to [REASON_SIGNALED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationExitInfo#REASON_SIGNALED).
As per documentation, it means App died due to result of Os signal.
I wanted to understand more in details about this like what does **status = 9** means in below log snippet. Any Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks..

```
ApplicationExitInfo #0:
          timestamp=2022-10-19 04:01:04.842
          pid=6982
          realUid=10314
          packageUid=10314
          definingUid=10314
          user=0
          process=com.example.sampletest
          reason=2 (SIGNALED)
          status=9
          importance=100
          pss=268MB
          rss=274MB
          description=null
          state=39 bytes
          trace=null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the Android 11 feature overview page about app exit reasons, and look specifically in the blue *Note box: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/features#app-process-exit-reasons

> Note: Some devices cannot report low-memory kills. On these devices, the getHistoricalProcessExitReasons() method returns REASON_SIGNALED instead of REASON_LOW_MEMORY, and the return value of getStatus() is SIGKILL.
>
> To check whether a device can report low-memory kills, call ActivityManager.isLowMemoryKillReportSupported().

So if your application does not trigger any exit-signals, and your device does not support the low memory kill report, this is probably your reason.

Answer (score 1):

According to this piece of [Android Documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/ApplicationExitInfo):

> Application process was killed by the system's low memory killer, meaning the system was under memory pressure at the time of kill.

I guess you have too much memory usage. For example, have you freed up resources like Bitmaps, or have you unregistered the listeners and broadcast receivers?

It is better to first find the memory leaks with the [Canari](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) application and then check again.